# How to generated Build number with Git repository using Maven Build number plugin ?

Tags: java, git, maven, maven-plugin, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I am configuring maven build number plugin with Git repository in my project, its working fine in my local machine.

If I am building code in my local machine using maven ,so the generated build number is from my local machine or it takes from Git repository ?

As I am using Git repository for Build Number plugin, so is it necessary to give the credentials.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, and it actually says 'it depends'.

Since git is a distributed version control system once you clone a repository you have the whole history of the project available locally. Push and fetch operations keep remote and local copies in sync.

So now it depends on how exactly the build number plugin is configured to know where it gets the build number from.